# MKMapView display showsScale distance in km (not mi)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

The MKMapView shows the distance scale in miles (mi) (top-left)
This there a way to display all distances in kilometres (km) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question.

It's the regional settings that determines what measurement to use.

I was getting miles on my simulator because it's region is currently US.

On my device the distance is displayed in kilometres. (Region is set correctly)